# Sharing material themes with different angular apps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an existing Angular app that has a custom Material Theme. Now I need to create another Angular app (in the same repo) that should have the same theme.

What is the best way to share the styles between the two applications? Copying the styles from one to another is a way, but I'm sure it is not the best thing to do.

Comment: Look for angular 10 workspaces, if you are using Angular 10

Answer (score 4):

There are only 2 options available, I believe:

1. Copy theme files (no brainer!)
2. Create a library and share it using package manager. You could use public or private package manager.